# CodeIgniter changing the base_url

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm new to using PHP and CodeIgniter. I have a folder named *ePOD* inside the htdocs which is fully working and I've copied all the content of it (ePOD folder) to another empty folder name which is *ePODglobe*. Both of these folders are inside the htdocs.

I've changed the `base_url` inside the ePODglobe folder and as I've tested the `base_url` it returned an `Object Not Found` Error. Aside from the `base_url` of ePODglobe, what else should I need to check and modify to make it working?

`base_url` inside ePOD folder(this is the original and working base_url):

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/ePOD/';
```

`base_url` inside ePODglobe folder:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/ePODglobe/';
```

Comment: When left blank, CI will in most cases correctly determine the base_url: `$config['base_url'] =''`.

Comment: @Mudshark, sorry but can you please elaborate?

Comment: just try `$config['base_url'] ='';` in your config.php file, see if that solves your problem.

Comment: did you use htaccess if yes than change the folder name in htaccess also to your new folder name